# Apache sqoop is not getting installed in MacOS by brew or jar

Tags: macos, sqoop

I have hadoop installed in my system. I want to copy data from postgresql table to hdfs using apache sqoop. I tried installing sqoop by brew on my mac, but I'm getting this error:

```
Error: sqoop has been disabled because it is deprecated upstream!
```

I tried to install sqoop by following  [these](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/Installation.html) instructions, but my mac is not letting me create directory in /usr/lib/sqoop.

How can I install sqoop in my mac?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Brew package is disabled because Sqoop is a retired Apache project.

I suggest you use Brew or pip to install Spark, then you can use JDBC functions from SparkSQL to read Postgres and write to HDFS